# Installation Process of Flutter

Tags: flutter

C:\Users\aakas>flutter doctor

'Information' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'Information' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Error: Unable to find git in your PATH.

[1][How to fix it, I already set the environment variable and dart is working but flutter is not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otSyg.png)

Comment: Did you install git?

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated your Flutter path in your Environment variables?
update your path in environment variables and restart your system and run again flutter doctor in Command Terminal.

Comment: Yes i updated flutter path in environment variable and restarted the PC but still it shows same problem

Comment: Try to compare your installation process with the flutter official **Documents.** [https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows]

Answer (score 0):

To run Flutter on your device properly you have to install these following things first:

- Android Studio
- Chrome (Browser)
- Git
- IntelliJ (Not sure if it's a must or not but `flutter doctor` does check for it)

Otherwise, you'll face difficulties for not installing any of them.
The following is the result I got after running `flutter doctor` on my device and it shows the things it checks for Flutter to be properly running.

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.6.0-11.0.pre, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1288], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2021.2)
[√] VS Code (version 1.62.1)
[√] Connected device (2 available)
```